# Pharo Smalltalk test failure because message not understood

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, pharo-5

I am starting to learn Smalltalk, using Pharo 5. I am now following a [tutorial from the squeak guys](http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/) to get some proper grip on the syntax, etc.

I am in the beginning, I have only two classes (a class BlankCell and a BlanCellTestCase class for the unit test). The Blankcell has some messages implemented already, I am at the very end of section 1.9.

The beahavior is well implemented, because on the playground:

```
| cell exit |
cell := BlankCell new.
exit := cell exitSideFor: #north.
exit = #south
"the last statement properly returns a true or false"
```

On the testcase there are three tests, only one fails (related to the exitSide):

```
testCellExitSides
   "Test the exit sides."
    | cell exit |
    cell := BlankCell new.
    exit := cell exitSideFor: #north.
    self assert: [ exit = #south ].
    exit := cell exitSideFor: #east. 
    self assert: [ exit = #west ].
    exit := cell exitSideFor: #south.
    self assert: [ exit = #north ].
    exit := cell exitSideFor: #west.
    self assert: [ exit = #east ].
```

The error message is

```
MessageNotUnderstood:BlockClosure>>ifFalse:
```

The `doesNotUnderstand` message is sent an argument pointing to the sentence `[ exit = #south ]`

Does anyone understand what may be going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TestCase>>assert:` expects a boolean, not a block.

So

`self assert: [ exit = #south ].`

should be written as

`self assert: exit = #south`

For string comparisons the preferable way is to use the following:

`self assert: exit equals: #south`

Because that way you will a see diff of the strings and just a boolean failure.

---

**BUT**

`Object>>assert:` expects a block, not a boolean.

However you would use this assert inside your regular code, not for code testing.

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial actually uses the message `should:` which expects a block. The compiler suggested using assert instead and I did not notice that difference in the argument.

Comment: `#south` is a ByteObject and as such does not implement the `equals:` message. (or does this depend on the ST implementation?).

Comment: @rll `#south` is a `Symbol`; but why would it need understand `equals:` message? The whole message is `assert:equals:` (with two arguments)

Comment: Ok, I was looking at it as two messages, hence the confusion.